# Memory efficient image resize in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, image-manipulation

I am trying to reduce the size of images retrieved form the camera (so ~5-8 mega pixels) down to one a a few smaller sizes (the largest being 1024x768). I Tried the following code but I consistently get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.image, null, opt);
int imgWidth = image.getWidth();
int imgHeight = image.getHeight();

// Constrain to given size but keep aspect ratio
float scaleFactor = Math.min(((float) width) / imgWidth, ((float) height) / imgHeight);

Matrix scale = new Matrix();
scale.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
final Bitmap scaledImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight, scale, false);

image.recycle();
```

It looks like the OOM happens during the `createBitmap`. Is there a more memory efficient way to do this? Perhaps something that doesn't require me to load the entire original into memory?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you decode the bitmap with the BitmapFactory, pass in a BitmapFactory.Options object and specify inSampleSize. This is the best way to save memory when decoding an image.

Here's a sample code [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966)

Answer (score 1):

Are you taking the picture with the camera within your application? If so, you should set the picture size to a smaller one in the first place when they're being captured via `android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize`

Comment: No, I am using the `android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to let the user select an image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question that I answered and show how to go about dynamically loading the proper image size.

[out of memory exception + analyzing hprof file dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155628/out-of-memory-exception-analyzing-hprof-file-dump/29637906#29637906)