# React Native Android] Resize image and upload to backend server

Tags: android, react-native

The photos captured with the device are big. I want to upload them to my backend server after resizing them (scaling them) to more reasonable sizes (less than 800x800). I hoped to use `ImageEditor` module's `coprImage()` function, but running it with a large image results in a `OutOfMemory` exception. I assume that since the module tries to decode a large image and store it in memory, the app crashes.

What I need is the following:

Input

```
{
  width: 3100,
  height: 2500,
  uri: content://android/1 (some location in Android device)
}
```

Output

```
{
  width: 800,
  height: 650,
  uri: content://android/1/resized (some location in Android device)
}
```

Then I can grab this uri to send the picture to my backend server, and delete the resized photo from the device.

I assume that I will have to write a `NativeModule` so I can resize an image without loading a large decoded image into memory. React Native's `Image` component uses [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html) to handle resizing before rendering them, but I don't think it provides a way to resize an image and temporarily save it in fs.

Any help would be appreciated.

References:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
2. http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html
3. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html
4. [Memory efficient image resize in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219672/memory-efficient-image-resize-in-android)

Answer (score 11):

Expo library has an image manipulator that can resize and more:

```
import { ImageManipulator } from 'expo';
```

...

```
const manipResult = await ImageManipulator.manipulate(
    imageUri,
    [{ resize: { width: 640, height: 480 } }],
    { format: 'jpg' }
);
```

`manipResult` will return an object with the new uri, width and height.

Find it here:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator.html

Comment: Current link: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/

Answer (score 3):

In my app I use [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker) which works really well.

If you don't want to use it, have a look into [this function source](https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker/blob/61801bb71be8b4a2306d80e1552f54ab1d55d775/android/src/main/java/com/imagepicker/ImagePickerModule.java#L591-L660) to see how resizing is done. 
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with [react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer)? For me it works pretty well, I'm using it with [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera), it looks like this:

```
  fromCamera() {
    let newWidth = 800;
    let newHeight = 650;
    this.refs.camera.capture()
    .then((data) => {
      ImageResizer.createResizedImage(data.path, newWidth, newHeight, 'JPEG', 100, rotation)
      .then(uri => {
        // send to backend
      }
    })
  }
```

Original image is saving on device with `uri: data.path`, so there are no problems with memory.

Comment: from where i get ImageResizer component ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets check out [this](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-upload-images-queue). It will provide you detailed description about your issue for resizing and uploading to backend server.

Answer (score 0):

Incase If you want to send Base64 String you can check the code below

how to install and link with android please check this link

https://github.com/TBouder/react-native-asset-resize-to-base64

// this code is for resizing and pushing to array only

```
let images = [];
NativeModules.RNAssetResizeToBase64.assetToResizedBase64(
            response.uri,
            newWidth,
            newHeight,
            (err, base64) => {
              if (base64 != null) {
                const imgSources = { uri: base64 };
                this.setState({
                  image: this.state.image.concat(imgSources)
                });
                 this.state.image.map((item, index) => {
                  images.push(item);
                });
                if (err) {
                  console.log(err, "errors");
                }
              }
            }
          );
```